OpenVPN Configuration Failing on Linux Mint 22 After Successful Setup on Mint 21
I’m using OpenVPN on Linux Mint 21, and it works fine.
Now I’m trying to use the same configuration on Linux Mint 22, but the connection fails.
I have no idea how to solve this. Can anyone help me, please?
This is the output when I run the command:
openvpn --config ink49wall-UDP4-1218-lorenzo.nbk.ovpn
2024-10-14 10:54:03 OpenSSL: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported:Global default library context, Algorithm (RC2-40-CBC : 0), Properties ()
2024-10-14 10:54:03 OpenSSL: error:11800071:PKCS12 routines::mac verify failure:
2024-10-14 10:54:03 Decoding PKCS12 failed. Probably wrong password or unsupported/legacy encryption
2024-10-14 10:54:03 Error: private key password verification failed


As the output suggests, the algorithm is not supported and causes the issue.
I've edited the /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf configuration file as suggested in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74416513/3384675
